# How to insert blob data into Teradata table?

Tags: database, blob, teradata

I have following table. I need to insert a BLOB which is more than 64K. I am table to do following:

```
create table MYtable
(c1 INTEGER
,c2 BLOB
);

INSERT MYtable(
9292,'DEADBEEF1DEADBEEF2DEADBEEF3DEADBEEFDEADBEEF1DEADBEEF2DEADBEEF3DEADBEEF44DEADBEEF1DEADBEEF2DEADBEEF3DEADBEEFDEADBEEF1DEADBEEF2DEADBEEF3DEADBEEF44'XB
);
```

If I want to insert a blob more than 64KB, the corresponding string will be so huge. Can't I insert an image or pdf file which is more than 64KB in BLOB?

Comment: "If I want to insert a blob more than 64KB, the corresponding string will be so huge" - So?

Comment: @MitchWheat So I was thinking to insert a file into that column rather than that string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly insert more than 64k, the (B|C)LOB data must be stored in a file.

I'd suggest reading this articles on Teradata's Developer Exchange first:

http://developer.teradata.com/applications/articles/large-objects-part-1-loading

Comment: The attached article gives an example where a `FileInputStream` is used, but I just successfully "directly inserted" 5MB using a `ByteArrayInputStream`.  Is the article out of date?

Comment: @jordanpg: No, it reads *For example if you wish to store (persist) a Java Object in your table, you could convert it to a byte array (byte []) and use a ByteArrayInputStream to store it in a BLOB column*

Comment: Ah, thanks I missed that...  I was also curious about the above comment about being unable to directly insert >64k.

Comment: @jordanpg: The OP tried to load using a SQL INSERT and then you must use a file.

Comment: I see -- you mean inserting bytes as text in a SQL INSERT statement as opposed to a `PreparedStatement` that happens to contain an INSERT.